# mvc image button to change status

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, dynamic

How am I supposed to change only one entity inside my table with button click event.I have Implemented Scaffold template for CRUD operation but also need to make change the table attribute with button click.

I am Using This method to change value

```
public ActionResult Enable(int id, tbl_users tbl_users)
{
    if (id > 0)
    {
        if (tbl_users.Status == 0)
        {
            tbl_users.Status = 1;
            db.tbl_users.Add(tbl_users);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
        }
        else
        {
            tbl_users.Status = 1;
            db.tbl_users.Add(tbl_users);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
}
```

Green checkMark is the button for active user and when the user is inactive simply by clicking that button user should be disable and button should change
I am currently using this code to display those buttons in view :

```
@if (item.Status == 1)
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("Enable", "Account", new { id = item.Id })" title="Enable status">
    <img alt="Enable status" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/active_icon.png" )" height="32" width="32">
    </a>

    @*<a href="/Account/Enable/@item.Id"><img src="~/Content/Images/active_icon.png"  height="32" width="32"/>
    </a>*@
}
else
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("Enable", "Account", new { id = item.Id })" title="Enable status">
    <img alt="Enable status" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/inactive_icon.png")" height="32" width="32">
    </a>
    @*<img src="~/Content/Images/inactive_icon.png" height="32" width="32"/>*@
}
```

[image: View Image]

[Database Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hclDw.png)

Comment: What you exaclty want to do?

Comment: I want to change that green check ma button to red after clicking it and change i have already implemented it. but could not change the status attribute in my database. that is 1 to 0 and 0 to 1. 1 for active and 0 for inactive. Please Let me know if more information is needed to make you understand.